# JBPM Fact model is not loading into JVM when rules are coming from central nexus repository

Tags: drools, kie, kie-workbench

**JBPM Fact model is not loading into JVM when rules are coming from central nexus repository**

Following steps :

1. Created a rule into Kie-Workbench.
2. Add model(domain) dependency into kie-workbench project.
3. Build & Deploy.
4. I am able to see project jar into nexus repository.
5. Now i am calling this repository from java code, see the below code -
   Artifact name :

   ```
   KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
   KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(ks.newReleaseId("com.ek.tooltest", "drl-jar-test", "1.1.2"));      
   KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession();           
   kSession.insert(new ITSRWorkflow("pc",6, "abc"));           
   int noOfRulesFired = kSession.fireAllRules();
   ```

**ERROR** It is not getting the artifacts from Nexus(central repository)..
Please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

I got resolved the issue by doing following activity :

I added the fact model into nexus repository , then its loading from nexus.